# The inductive and projective limits of compact Hausdorff topological groups

Tags: gn.general-topology, limits-and-colimits

Are there conditions known under which the inductive or projective limit of a family of compact Hausdorff topological groups is compact? (For instance, such a result is valid for the projective limit if the groups are totally disconnected, but this hypothesis is too constraining.)

Comment: I believe for projective limits it is always compact: its is a closed subgroup of a product of compact spaces.

Comment: Inductive limits of compact things will almost never be compact.

Comment: Of course, one should specify the category in which one is taking (co)limits; I guess you mean in the category of topological groups? 


Comment: Right. If I'm not mistaken, the category of compact Hausdorff topological groups has all limits and colimits, but for most of the colimits it is necessary to take the Bohr compactification of the colimit in topological groups. 

Comment: Thank you all so far for your very quick reaction.

Benjamin Steinberg, yes, with Tychonov's theorem; this is what I was suspecting too, I was just needing some confirmation. Could you please comment more on the inductive limit, since this is what interests me more?

Qiaochu Yuan, could you give any bibliographical hint? I have no experience on the subject.

Todd Trimble: yes.

Comment: I should think how general it is, anyway usually the caracterzation of  compact sets in the inductive limit of a sequence $G_j\subset G_{j+1}$ is, exactly those sets already included in one $G_j$, and compact there. This is the case e.g. of $\mathbb{R}^\omega=\lim_{\rightarrow}\mathbb{R}^n$

Comment: Pietro Majer, my family of objects is not necessarily indexed by the natural numbers. Of course, I could change this, but is it worth it? Would I surely gain something useful?

Comment: Yes, I do not think anything changes...

Comment: the forgetful functor $U: T_2.Compact.spaces\to Topological.spaces$  create limits, and limits commute by groups-object structure, then T_2.Compact.groups category  is complete.

ABout colimits, filtrant colimits (direct limits) commute by groups structure, but in general filtrant colimits of T_2.compat spaces is not T_2.compat, anyway if the filtant diagram has a weak final object (in the definition of final object take off uniqueness) the colimit is compact (but may be not $T_2$).

Qiaochu Yuan: TOpological groups category is  cocomplete? Do you know a precise reference?    

Comment: Sergio Buschi, I've never studied any category theory, therefore could you please translate in set-theoretic language the phrase: "if the filtrant diagram has a weak final object"? You also say that it *may* not be T2. When would it be, then? Thank you.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg Any infinitely presented, finitely generated profinite group is an inductive limit of compact groups in a nontrivial way. Inductive systems are often thought with injections, but inductive limits of surjections are also important.